# Check if lightning component implements an interface based on component name

Tags: aura

I am creating a configuration page which will allow user to enter lightning component name (which is supposed to implement an interface).
But before saving the lightning component name I would like to check if that component has implemented that interface.

Something similar to this: [Determine if a Type implements an interface](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3985/determine-if-a-type-implements-an-interface)

But in the context of aura component.

I know the component.instanceOf() can do the trick, but for that I may end up creating the component. (Not 100% sure if required attributes will fail the component creation though).
If anyone already solved it, could you please guide.

Comment: We implemented something like this for classes that extended a base class by using query to get the class body and parse it. Not a decent way but it did work. Is that an option for you?

Comment: @manjit5190 Thank you for the reply. I am looking for something in terms of aura. eg. If a lightning component implements "appHostable" salesforce shows just that component in drop-down for selection, when we create lightning tabs. I am trying to do something similar.